# Notified Immediately after setting reminder even after selecting long period of time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am trying to make an reminder app. Everything is fine only the problem is that its notify Immediately after tapping saving button. After 3-10 seconds. Even I select the long period of time.

This is the class code where I am setting the values from user.

```js
package com.logictex.docchatappointment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.logictex.reminder.ReminderManager;
import com.logictex.reminder.RemindersDbAdapter;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class ReminderEditActivity extends Activity {

 // 
 // Dialog Constants
 //
 private static final int DATE_PICKER_DIALOG = 0;
 private static final int TIME_PICKER_DIALOG = 1;
 
 // 
 // Date Format 
 //
 private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
 private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm";
 public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm:ss";
 
 private EditText mTitleText;
    private EditText mBodyText;
 private TextInputLayout inputLayoutTitle;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private Button mTimeButton;
    private Button mConfirmButton;
    private Long mRowId;
    private RemindersDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Calendar mCalendar;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
        
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);
        
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
  inputLayoutTitle = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_title);
        mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_date);
        mTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_time);
      
        mConfirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
       
        mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                       : null;
      
        registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
    }

 private void setRowIdFromIntent() {
  if (mRowId == null) {
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
   mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
         : null;
   
  }
 }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDbHelper.close(); 
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDbHelper.open(); 
     setRowIdFromIntent();
  populateFields();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
     switch(id) {
      case DATE_PICKER_DIALOG: 
       return showDatePicker();
      case TIME_PICKER_DIALOG: 
       return showTimePicker(); 
     }
     return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
    
  private DatePickerDialog showDatePicker() {
  
  
  DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(ReminderEditActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    updateDateButtonText(); 
   }
  }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
  return datePicker; 
 }

   private TimePickerDialog showTimePicker() {
  
     TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute); 
    updateTimeButtonText(); 
   }
  }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true); 
  
     return timePicker; 
 }
  
 private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {

  mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(DATE_PICKER_DIALOG);  
   }
  }); 
  
  
  mTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(TIME_PICKER_DIALOG); 
   }
  }); 
  
  mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mTitleText.getText().toString()))
    {
     inputLayoutTitle.setError("Field can't be Empty");
    }
    else {
     saveState();
     setResult(RESULT_OK);
     Toast.makeText(ReminderEditActivity.this, getString(R.string.task_saved_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     finish();
    }
         }
          
        });
  
    updateDateButtonText(); 
       updateTimeButtonText();
 }
   
    private void populateFields()  {
     
   
     
     // Only populate the text boxes and change the calendar date
     // if the row is not null from the database. 
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor reminder = mDbHelper.fetchReminder(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(reminder);
            mTitleText.setText(reminder.getString(
                 reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            mBodyText.setText(reminder.getString(
                    reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
            

            // Get the date from the database and format it for our use. 
            SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
            Date date = null;
   try {
    String dateString = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME)); 
    date = dateTimeFormat.parse(dateString);
             mCalendar.setTime(date); 
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("ReminderEditActivity", e.getMessage(), e); 
   } 
        } else {
         // This is a new task - add defaults from preferences if set. 
         SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
         String defaultTitleKey = getString(R.string.pref_task_title_key); 
         String defaultTimeKey = getString(R.string.pref_default_time_from_now_key); 
         
         String defaultTitle = prefs.getString(defaultTitleKey, null);
         String defaultTime = prefs.getString(defaultTimeKey, null); 
         
         if(defaultTitle != null)
          mTitleText.setText(defaultTitle); 
         
         if(defaultTime != null)
          mCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(defaultTime));
         
        }
        
        updateDateButtonText(); 
        updateTimeButtonText(); 
         
    }

 private void updateTimeButtonText() {
  // Set the time button text based upon the value from the database
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT); 
        String timeForButton = timeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()); 
        mTimeButton.setText(timeForButton);
 }

 private void updateDateButtonText() {
  // Set the date button text based upon the value from the database 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT); 
        String dateForButton = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()); 
        mDateButton.setText(dateForButton);
 }
    
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }
    

    
    private void saveState() {
        String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
        String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT); 
     String reminderDateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

        if (mRowId == null) {
         
         long id = mDbHelper.createReminder(title, body, reminderDateTime);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateReminder(mRowId, title, body, reminderDateTime);
        }
       
        new ReminderManager(this).setReminder(mRowId, mCalendar);
    }
    
}
```

This is the `ReminderManager.java` class.

```js
public class ReminderManager {

 private Context mContext; 
 private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
 
 public ReminderManager(Context context) {
  mContext = context; 
  mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 }
 
 public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {
  
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId); 

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 
        
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
 }
}
```

Here is the `OnAlarmReceiver.java` class.

```js
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName(); 
 
 
 @Override 
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Received wake up from alarm manager.");
  
  long rowid = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
  
  WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);
  
  Intent i = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class); 
  i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowid);  
  context.startService(i);
   
 }
}
```

And here is the `ReminderService.java` class.

```js
public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {

 NotificationManager manager;
 Notification myNotication;

 public ReminderService() {
  super("ReminderService");
   }

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
 @Override
 public void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
  Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
  Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
   
  manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class); 
  notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 
  
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 
  
  /*Notification note=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), System.currentTimeMillis());
  note.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title), getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), pi);
  note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
  note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;*/

  Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ReminderService.this);

  builder.setAutoCancel(true);
  builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
  builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title));
  builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message));
  builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
  builder.setContentIntent(pi);
  builder.setOngoing(true);
  builder.setNumber(100);
  builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
  builder.build();

  myNotication = builder.getNotification();

  
  // An issue could occur if user ever enters over 2,147,483,647 tasks. (Max int value). 
  // I highly doubt this will ever happen. But is good to note. 
  int id = (int)((long)rowId);
  manager.notify(id, myNotication);
  
  
 }
}
```

And here is the `RemindersDbAdapter.java` class code.

```js
public class RemindersDbAdapter {

 //
 // Databsae Related Constants
 //
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "com.logictex.reminder";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    
 public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time"; 
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    
    
    private static final String TAG = "ReminderDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    
    /**
     * Database creation SQL statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
              + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_BODY + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);"; 

    

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public RemindersDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public RemindersDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    
    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new reminder using the title, body and reminder date time provided. 
     * If the reminder is  successfully created return the new rowId
     * for that reminder, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the reminder
     * @param body the body of the reminder
     * @param reminderDateTime the date and time the reminder should remind the user
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createReminder(String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime); 

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the reminder with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all reminders in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all reminders
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the reminder that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching reminder, if found
     * @throws SQLException if reminder could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

                mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the reminder using the details provided. The reminder to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title, body and reminder date time
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to update
     * @param title value to set reminder title to
     * @param body value to set reminder body to
     * @param reminderDateTime value to set the reminder time. 
     * @return true if the reminder was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `OnAlarmReceiver` Did you check that if the `when.getTimeInMillis()` is providing correct time or not? `Alarm manager` triggers `broadcast receiver` immediately when the date/time is already passed.

as you didn't gave the code of `RemindersDbAdapter.java` there is also a possiblility that this code from `ReminderManager.java` is not behaving as you expected.I think below code gets `mRowId=null` and directly goes to else clause and set `String defaultTimeKey = getString(R.string.pref_default_time_from_now_key);`

```
private void populateFields()  {



    // Only populate the text boxes and change the calendar date
    // if the row is not null from the database. 
    if (mRowId != null) {
    -------
    }
    else {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
        String defaultTitleKey = getString(R.string.pref_task_title_key); 
        String defaultTimeKey = getString(R.string.pref_default_time_from_now_key); 

        String defaultTitle = prefs.getString(defaultTitleKey, null);
        String defaultTime = prefs.getString(defaultTimeKey, null); 

        if(defaultTitle != null)
            mTitleText.setText(defaultTitle); 

        if(defaultTime != null)
            mCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(defaultTime));
    }
```

> thus it's creating an alarm at a time that is already passed,that's why the alarm is triggering immediately.

Comment: please see my edited post. I have inserted RemindersDbAdapter class.

Comment: I am get this value in when.getTimeInMillis()
"java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1483945851242,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Karachi,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=2,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=9,DAY_OF_YEAR=9,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=10,SECOND=51,MILLISECOND=242,ZONE_OFFSET=18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]"

Comment: Why is the month=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start it after 3 seconds do :

```
when.getTimeInMillis() + (3 * 1000)
```

so

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis()+ (3 * 1000) ,pi);
```

If you want to start after 3 minutes do:

```
when.getTimeInMillis()+ ( 3* (60* 1000))
```

so

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis() +( 3* (60* 1000)) , pi);
```

*`getTimeInMillis()`* give you current time in milliseconds thus your alarm get triggered right away.

Comment: how do I calculate time entered by user?

Comment: That's easy, for `n` *minutes*, calculate `n * 60*1000` *milliseconds*  so `when.getTimeInMillis() + (n * 60*1000)` . For `n` *hours*, calculate `n* 3600*1000` so `when.getTimeInMillis() + (n* 3600*1000)`. This `when.getTimeInMillis()` is basically just current time in milliseconds (unix time stamps/1000 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your alarm doesn't fire immediately due to it being set for a time that has already passed in the current day, put in a check to see if the time has already passed, and if it has then set the calendar to the next day when constructing the `Calendar` object:

```
 if(mCalendar.before(System.currentTimeMillis())){
     mCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 }
```

`Calendar.DATE, 1` will take the time and add a day to it, so if you set the alarm for 7:00am and it is currently 3:00pm, it will set it for 7:00am tomorrow, instead of firing immediately because 7:00am has already passed that day.